# How to create/use a single instance of a php class with Laravel Queues

Tags: php, laravel, singleton

Sorry this is so long but not sure how to get my concerns across.

I am using Laravel 5.8 with php 7.2.*
I have a php class like:

```
class PushNotificationsJob implements ShouldQueue
```

This is used to send push notifications to mobile devices and is currently working fine, well for the most part.
With Apple's restrictions they do not want you to connect and disconnect over and over and if you do it too many times in a short period of time they will return a Denial of Service (DOS). So the first of two design problems is I need to be able to save a curl connection to be used over and over. Right now I connect, send notifications and then disconnect. The problem is the events that dictate when a notification needs to be sent is not predictable nor can it be controlled. The second design issue I now have is I really need to create a table which contains a record per mobile device per notification type. The main reason I need to do this is I need to defer sending a certain type of notification until I have 15 seconds without needing to send that notification type to that mobile device again. So the problem I would have is if every time I queue to run the PushNotificationsJob class it runs a different instance then I may end up having two instances running at the same time and both may query the same records and both send the same notification when it should only be sent once.

Of course the reason I am using a Queue is to off load the process of sending the notification off the main thread so it does not slow down the response to the client.

I have a feeling people who don't understand why this works this way will suggest options that don't apply so I will add details here in case you need additional info. What is happening is I have Cameras (1,000s of them) that are taking pictures when they detect motion and they upload to my server. I can't control when they detect motion and upload. When a camera uploads a photo via the REST api I provide I then need to look up the owner of that camera and send them a notification. (There are other things that cause a notification to be sent but this is the best example) So the issue is the Camera may have 1 photo or 50 photos to upload. And the user wants the notification ASAP. If the camera has more than 1 photo to upload it usually only takes about 5 - 8 seconds to upload the next photo. So what I want to do is defer sending the first notification for 15 seconds, But if another photo is uploaded before the first notification is sent then I want to reset the timer for the notification for 15 more seconds. Thus once the camera goes more than 15 seconds without uploading a photo then I would send one notification not 50.

My thoughts are if I was somehow able to create a single instance of the Class that is running in another thread and every time I needed to send a Push Notification I would "wake up" the class by calling some method to tell it their is activity. Then it could re-query the table and process those records which are "ready" to be sent. This would solve both issues, This instance could hold a single curl connection to Apple and since there would only be one instance it would be free to query the records and process and delete when it is done and not worry about conflicting with another instance doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very interesting and I like the concept.

How do you have your queue worker set up?  If you are using **supervisor** to manage your worker, then it should be a long running process.  This is why you have to call `artisan queue:restart` any time you make changes to the code base. I've been known to forget about this and end up tearing my hair out wondering why changes aren't working.

Due to this fact, I imagine you could bind a singleton to the service container and call it when you need to do work.  The CURL connection would be stored within the singleton, which you can register in a service provider.  The only time a new connection would be created is if the queue worker died and was restarted.

**Of course, you would need to work this out so it only ran from the queue worker and not every time the application is booted.**

EDIT: I have added a check to make sure the app is running from console (as the queue worker would be) before creating a connection and binding the singleton. I'm not sure how to do this for queue workers only, but if I find out, I'll let you know. At the moment, you would just need to be aware of other artisan commands.

App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```php
use App;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        // make sure we're running from the console 
        // and not every time the app is booted
        if (App::runningInConsole()) {

            // create your connection
            $connection = new YourCurlConnection();

            $this->app->singleton('App\Support\PushNotificationHelper', function ($app) use ($connection) {
                return new App\Support\PushNotificationHelper($connection);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

App\Support\PushNotificationHelper.php

```php
class PushNotificationHelper
{
    // your CURL instance
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct($connection)
    {
        // store via dependency injection
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function sendNotification($message)
    {
        // send notification using stored connection
    }
}
```

App/Jobs/PushNotificationsJob.php

```php
class PushNotificationsJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    protected $message;

    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $message = $this->message;

        // get the singleton
        $helper = app('App\Support\PushNotificationHelper');

        // send the message using the singleton
        $helper->sendNotification($message);
    }
}
```

Of course, you would need to ensure **supervisor** is only running one queue worker if you don't want overlapping connections, as I think the documentation lists eight workers in the default config.

Just an additional note, you may want to trigger a restart of the queue occasionally via the scheduler just to make sure you aren't tying up excess memory along the way.

I hope this gives you some ideas and good luck!

Comment: wow, thank you so much for the detail and clarity of your answer. And yes you are right on the money. You made one comment I need clarity on and it deals with supervisor (which I am using to run the queue worker) Inside my *.conf file for supervisor is a field called "numprocs" which is currently set to 8. What I think you are saying is that must control the number of Queue Jobs that will be launched at any given time? So simply by setting that to a 1 would mean I would never have more than 1 PushNotificationsJob running at any given time?

Comment: All though if that is the case it would defiantly solve my issue but may also create another issue. I have other queue jobs for sending email and other stuff so now I am really restricting my app from getting these task done by making all queue jobs get in a single line and wait their turn so-to-speak? Hmmm if there was a way to say only 1 PushNotificationsJob can run at a time but up to 8 other queue jobs could run?

Comment: Is there a way to leave numprocs at 8, Then have a "busy" flag in the PushNotificationHelper (PNH) singleton. Then in the PushNotificationJob (PNJ) we could ask the PNH if it is busy. If it is we somehow sleep/loop and check back, when it is not busy we can continue. When the PNJ is done it would tell PNH it is done. This way only one PNJ runs at a time but other queue jobs could run in parallel?

Comment: What exactly are Apple's connection limitations?  Could you get away with running 8 CURL connections at once if only one was actually actively being used?  If so, I may have a possible solution.  Then I imagine you could kill off the unused connections after a period of time so they aren't always running.